# How to ajax post on URL parameter change without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Depending on the change in URL parameter my values in the html changes. So basically i am passing these values to a json file. Since the page is refreshing because of the post my values are getting erased.I tried event prevent default, but its not working for me.

```
var carryOver ={"Jan":"","Feb":""};
var parameters = getParameterByName('month')//gets the current URL parameter
if(parameters == '01-2017'){
    $('#monthQuota').html(janQuota);
    carryOver["Jan"] = 300;
}
else if(parameters == '02-2017'){
    carryOver["Feb"] = 400;
}
$(function() {
  $('parameters').on('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "utilization-2017-test.php",
        data: {
           json: JSON.stringify(monthBalances)
        }
      })
    })
 })
```

Comment: We are missing some details. First off `$('parameters').on('change'..)`` how is this fired? the `getParameterByName` that would be interesting. Is that query string parameters or hash parameters? Please [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `$('parameters')` .parameters is which attribute `class`,`id` or`tag`? `parameters` is a undefined one

Comment: Can you show us the HTML so we can see how your `<form>` is setup? We need to see this to examine your `.on()` jQuery method, which is what triggers first before your `.ajax()` method. If your form is reloading the page, it does not sound like the `.on()` is setup correctly. Have you tried console logging something inside the scope of the `.on()` function to make sure it's working? Also, make sure you're using the right jQuery selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  usually just using words, like `parameters` is for elements only, not classes or ids (`.foo`, `#foo` respectively).

Answer (score 0):

sir, javascript or jquery can detect the #(hash)change but not the parameter change.If you clicked on a link and #tag changed then the script or event will detect that and page will not get reloaded but to change parameters you are going for an entry in the browser Url, so your values getting refreshed.

So please do one thing that keeps a text box and enter values in that then you get the value from textbox and go for service call instead of taking input from URL